# Magmi is not Linking Simples to Configurable, CSV attached

Tags: magento, magmi

Both 2 Simple and 1 Configurable product is imported without errors but the simples are not attached to the configurable.

Please find attached my CSV.
Code: http://pastebin.com/nMeQ4fsr
Or get the CSV here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16640285/2raw-import-products-magento-1.7.csv

You will see I am using:
- simples_skus
- configurable_attributes 
- Configurable Item processor v1.3.7 is enabled with Perform simples/configurable link set to Yes

I can not see what is going wrong here. The attribute is set up correctly as I can manually create a configurable product from the Magento GUI with these simple products.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? If so would you kindly post your answer? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your skus.  the simple products need to have a sku that starts with the entire configurable products sku.  For example:

dope-jump-rope-small (simple) 
dope-jump-rope-medium (simple) 
dope-jump-rope (configurable)

Notice that the simple skus all start with the configurable sku.  Also, do you have the extra plugins installed?  If not, go to: http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/plugins/packages/

Get the plugins and after installation (you just upload the zip via the normal magmi panel) check the ones you want to turn on at the bottom of the page.  There is one that will auto match based on sku with the setup I described above.  I've used it like this many many times.

Comment: The simples_sku column should override the automatic matching of simple SKU's to configurable products - that is what I am trying to achieve. Yes I have the extra plugins package installed and configurable products plugin enabled.